# App crashes when adding code into fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android studio so I want to create an app that is using a navigation drawer to switch between 3 different fragments. I used the pre-built navigation drawer from android studio and I wanted to put some code into one of the fragments. But as soon as I initialize the TextView (or other things) the app immediately crashes when I try to open the fragment.

Here the code in the GalleryActivity:

```java
    public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentGalleryBinding binding;
    private TextView testTV;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textGallery;
        galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
        return root;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        initWidgets();

        testTV.setText("Hello");
    }

    public void initWidgets(){
       testTV = testTV.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

fragment_gallery.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
2022-06-07 03:32:20.006 12339-12339/com.example.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 12339
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.TextView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.testapp.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment.initWidgets(GalleryFragment.java:46)
        at com.example.testapp.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment.onViewCreated(GalleryFragment.java:40)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3019)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:551)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1764)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:488)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-06-07 03:32:20.040 12339-12339/com.example.testapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12339 SIG: 9
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize `testTV`, so it is null. Then you try and use it to initialize itself in this command, which is never going to work.

```java
testTV = testTV.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery); // testTV is null
```

If you must use `findViewById` you need to call it on the root view, which you could pass in from `onViewCreated` (e.g. `view.findViewById()`). However, since you are using a binding all of that is unnecessary, you can access the view directly from the binding like this

```java
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // no need to save testTV as a class member, it is already
    // saved in the binding
    binding.textGallery.setText("Hello");
}
```

The binding class is an auto-generated helper class that has already called `findViewById` on all the views in the layout and saved them as class members (it does that when you create it with the `MyBinding.inflate()` call). When using a binding you should almost never need to use `findViewById` nor should you need to store off individual views.